# CakePHP 3 - How to automatically show validation errors in view for form without model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm reviewing a basic contact form which is not associated with any model. I would like some advice on the best way to leverage Cake's automatic view rendering of field errors for this situation.

**Controller**

Performs validation through a custom Validator.

```
public function index()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {               

        // Validate the form
        $validator = new EnquiryValidator();
        $data = $this->request->data();
        $errors = $validator->errors($data);                    

        if (empty($errors)) {

            // Send email, etc.
            // ...
            // Refresh page on success

        }       
        // Show error
        $this->Flash->error('Unable to send email');
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?= $this->Form->create(); ?>

    <?= $this->Form->input('name', [
            'autofocus' => 'autofocus',
            'placeholder' => 'Your name',
            'required'
        ]);
    ?>

    <?= $this->Form->input('email', [
            'placeholder' => 'Your email address',
            'required'
        ]);
    ?>

    <?= $this->Form->input('subject', [
            'placeholder' => 'What would you like to discuss?',
            'required'
        ]);
    ?>

    <?= $this->Form->input('message', [
            'label' => 'Query',
            'placeholder' => 'How can we help?',
            'cols' => '30',
            'rows' => '10',
            'required'
        ]);
    ?>

    <div class="text-right">
        <?= $this->Form->button('Send'); ?>
    </div>

<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Currently the form will not show any errors next to the input fields. I assume it's because there is no entity associated with the form or something like that, but I'm not sure.

What is the best solution? Can the validation be performed in a better way to automatically provide field errors in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modelless forms

Use a modelless form. It can be used to validate data and perform actions, similar to tables and entities, and the form helper supports it just like entities, ie, you simply pass the modelless form instance to the `FormHelper::create()` call.

Here's the example from the docs, modified a little to match your case:

**src/Form/EnquiryForm.php**

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\...\EnquiryValidator;
use Cake\Form\Form;
use Cake\Form\Schema;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class EnquiryForm extends Form
{

    protected function _buildSchema(Schema $schema)
    {
        return $schema
            ->addField('name', 'string')
            ->addField('email', ['type' => 'string'])
            ->addField('subject', ['type' => 'string'])
            ->addField('message', ['type' => 'text']);
    }

    protected function _buildValidator(Validator $validator)
    {
        return new EnquiryValidator();
    }

    protected function _execute(array $data)
    {
        // Send email, etc.
        return true;
    }
}
```

**in your controller**

```
use App\Form\EnquiryForm;

// ...

public function index()
{
    $enquiry = new EnquiryForm();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($enquiry->execute($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success('Everything is fine.');
            // ...
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('Unable to send email.');
        }
    }
    $this->set('enquiry', $enquiry);
}
```

**in your view template**

```
<?= $this->Form->create($enquiry); ?>
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Modelless Forms](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html)**

Comment: Yep, forgot about this. Thanks, still doing everything in Cake 3 for the first time.